# cakePHP: question about ACL

Tags: cakephp, acl

I code `$this->Auth->allowedActions = array('index')`
 I use plugin poll, rating in  action index . 
When I enter action index, Auth dont allow because action of plugin poll,rating dont permit.

How to allow action of plugins poll,rating,...**to public** in controller (I dont want allow in controller of plugin ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it in AppController:

```
function beforeFilter(){
    if($this->plugin == 'poll'){
        $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('*');
    }
}
```